# I want to change php ext. to html ext. and disable direct access to php ext

Tags: php, .htaccess

Can someone help me.

I have the following code and I want to change .php to .html and if someone try to access .php then show the error 404.
The following code working if we remove '.html'. but I want to replace php to  html

```
# Rename Php to html extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

`index.php` open when type `index.html` and if somebuddy type `index.php` show error404.

Comment: if you are redirecting the .php to .html then why the 2nd rule will match. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for attention, I don't want to redirect .php  to .html.......if someone type index.html then only the webpage open

Comment: Why do you want to remove .php and show .html. Technically you should just remove /index.php for SEO friendly urls and have other pages which calls specific PHP scripts so it won't expose the script but even if you expose the script name if the code is secure than you don't have to worry.